# Exception not throwing?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have code resembling the following:

```
try{
    func1();
}
catch(Exception e){
    /Do something
}


static func1(){
    func2();
}

static func2(){
    //Exception thrown here
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
}
```

when an exception is thrown by the line of code in func2() I get no notification in the catch clause. I do not explicitly throw anything, I just have regular function declarations which are static- no "throw" appears anywhere.

Why isn't the exception propagating upwards to the catch statement??

Comment: Put the `try/catch` around `func2`. Also why are you going through `func1` to then call `func2`? Why not just call `func2`?

Comment: if no exception is explicitly thrown, how do you know `func2` causes an exception?

Comment: Did you tried to throw an `Exception` explicitly from `func2` ?

Comment: @BaliC this is obviously a sample.

Comment: In your example the exception is caught. There must be other problems in your code.

Comment: The Exception is caught in your catch clause. By "Notification", do you mean the popup by Visual Studio?

Comment: please note that there are some kinds of exceptions that you cannot catch (for example a StackOverflowException) - I don't think that is the case here but you never know. Just set the Exception-options (Debug->Exceptions) to halt on every exception and debug your code - know you should step into the exception and you can check the call-stack and step along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception will 'bubble up' until it is caught or crashes your app.

Your best bet is to use the Debugger.  Make sure you have it set to stop on HANDLED exceptions (Debug / Exceptions / Check the 'Thrown' box on the Common Language Runtime Exceptions).

Now run your code.  If func2 throws an exception - your code will break; regardless of whether or not it is handled.  You can step through the code and see what is handling it.

Answer (score 6):

No, the code is fine. There is something in your real code that you aren't showing us. That exception propagates fine:

```
using System;

static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        try{
            func1();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // works fine: FileNotFoundException
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
    static void func1(){
        func2();
    }    
    static void func2() {
        string filePath = "doesnot.exist";
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
    }
}
```

Candidates:

- anything involving a `try` is suspect - treble check it
- anything involving threading may have the exception somewhere else

Comment: I have a question about this solution. From what i've learned i thought that if there was an exception in Func2 it would just die and end there. The way i have always done it is i would put a Try Catch around Func2 and Throw Exception in the catch. That way it would raise up to the next level which would be the Try where Func2 is called. There i would also Throw Exception which takes it up to where function 1 is called. Now it is at the top level and will do whatever code is in the catch in the func1 call. Can you explain how this works without throwing the exception? Thanks